# How to save Ressources with SVG pattern fill

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have many paths within an SVG created dynamically with js.
To apply the background of the whole SVG I use the  approach.
Afterwards each pattern can be moved around with the mouse.
Now the thing is:
If too much paths are created, the whole thing gets laggy.
I assume that for each path, the whole image will be loaded.

Is there any solution to optimize this?
That just the specific (used) Area of the image gets loaded (for each path) instead of the whole image?

Example-Code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 7.01 18.986268221574345">
    <style>
        path {
            stroke: grey;
        }
    </style>
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="7" height="10">
            <image href="stephans-quintett.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="7" height="10"></image>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path d="M 0 0 l 1 0 l 0 1 l -1 0 z" stroke-width="0.005" fill="url(#img1)" style="filter: brightness(1);"></path>
    <path d="M 1 0 l 1 0 l 0 1 l -1 0 z" stroke-width="0.005" fill="url(#img1)" style="filter: brightness(1);"></path>
    <path d="M 2 0 l 1 0 l 0 1 l -1 0 z" stroke-width="0.005" fill="url(#img1)" style="filter: brightness(1);"></path>
    <path d="M 3 0 l 1 0 l 0 1 l -1 0 z" stroke-width="0.005" fill="url(#img1)" style="filter: brightness(1);"></path>
    <path d="M 4 0 l 1 0 l 0 1 l -1 0 z" stroke-width="0.005" fill="url(#img1)" style="filter: brightness(1);"></path>
    <path d="M 5 0 l 1 0 l 0 1 l -1 0 z" stroke-width="0.005" fill="url(#img1)" style="filter: brightness(1);"></path>
    <path d="M 6 0 l 1 0 l 0 1 l -1 0 z" stroke-width="0.005" fill="url(#img1)" style="filter: brightness(1);"></path>
</svg>
```

Edit:

Here with clip-path (doesnt seem to work)

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="puzzle"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 3.55756727664155 3.01">
            <style>
                path {
                    stroke: grey;
                }
            </style>
            <defs>
                <clipPath id"clip"="">
                    <rect x="0" y="0" height="0.5" width="0.5"></rect>
                </clipPath>
                <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="3" height="3">
                    <image href="https://stsci-opo.org/STScI-01G7DAAQBRZBGNHVN35FVCQWKQ.png" x="0" y="0" width="3" height="3"></image>
                </pattern>
            </defs>
            <path d="M 0 0 l 1 0 l 0 1 l -1 0 z" stroke-width="0.005" fill="url(#img1)" clip-path="url(#clip)"></path>
            <path d="M 1 0 l 1 0 l 0 1 l -1 0 z" stroke-width="0.005" fill="url(#img1)" clip-path="url(#clip)"></path>
            <path d="M 2 0 l 1 0 l 0 1 l -1 0 z" stroke-width="0.005" fill="url(#img1)" clip-path="url(#clip)"></path>
            <path d="M 0 1 l 1 0 l 0 1 l -1 0 z" stroke-width="0.005" fill="url(#img1)" clip-path="url(#clip)"></path>
            <path d="M 1 1 l 1 0 l 0 1 l -1 0 z" stroke-width="0.005" fill="url(#img1)" clip-path="url(#clip)"></path>
            <path d="M 2 1 l 1 0 l 0 1 l -1 0 z" stroke-width="0.005" fill="url(#img1)" clip-path="url(#clip)"></path>
            <path d="M 0 2 l 1 0 l 0 1 l -1 0 z" stroke-width="0.005" fill="url(#img1)" clip-path="url(#clip)"></path>
            <path d="M 1 2 l 1 0 l 0 1 l -1 0 z" stroke-width="0.005" fill="url(#img1)" clip-path="url(#clip)"></path>
            <path d="M 2 2 l 1 0 l 0 1 l -1 0 z" stroke-width="0.005" fill="url(#img1)" clip-path="url(#clip)"></path>
        </svg></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: filter: brightness(1) is a no-op but is unlikely to result in 0 processing. Better to just remove it.

Comment: onhover does filter: brightness(0.8); so onleave turns it back to 1

Comment: Onleave should do filter: none then.

Comment: How are you updating the svg on drag? Updating the single relevant path `d` attribute should be as fast for an image with only one path as for one with thousands, in my opinion.

Comment: With htmlobject.setAttribute("transform", "translate(X,Y)")